# I have a hard time understanding compareTo and its use

Tags: java, object

```
int testing = key.compareTo(node.entry.key());
```

key is an object, entry is a class .java created in the same folder. I have a hard time understanding what does that line of code is doing.

Comment: Can you specify what you don't understand from the documentation? Perhaps highlight what sentence(s) you're having trouble with?

Comment: It's comparing the object referenced by `key` to the object referenced by the return value of `node.entry.key()` and storing the result in the variable `testing`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html <- Helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo method is the sole member of the Comparable interface. There are two variants of this method. First method compares this String to another Object and second method compares two strings lexicographically.

```
int compareTo(Object o)
```

or

```
int compareTo(String anotherString)
```

**Why we need compareTo() ?**

Sorting is an essential part of application development, which you often required to implement in your system. in Java sorting is implemented using `Comparator` and `Comparable` in Java. Since we store java objects in `Collection` there are also certain Set and Map which provides automating sorting when you insert element on that e.g. `TreeSet` and `TreeMap`. to implement sorting you need to override either `compareTo(Object o)` method or `Comparable` class or `compare(Object o1, Object o2)` method of `Comparator` class. Most of the classes implement Comparable to implement natural order. for example if you are writing Employee object you probably want to implement Comparable interface and override `compareTo()` method to compare current employee with other employee based on ID. So essentially you need to override `compareTo()` because you need to sort elements in ArrayList or any other Collection.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-override-compareto-method-in.html#ixzz2yc2rJ9Er

Comment: There are not two variants of the `compareTo` method! There is only one: `compareTo(T other)`. To understand what that `T` is, you need to understand a bit about [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).